# Conditional over a time duration

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am looking to compare two values over a duration of 10 minutes. If A < B for the duration of 10 minutes then set C else do nothing.

```
from datetime import datetime
curr = datetime.now()
print (curr)
Curr_Plus_Ten = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
print (Curr_Plus_Ten)
```

The output from above is just 2012-10-16 11:37:55.224999 and 2012-10-16 11:47:55.224999

I figured I would use the current time and the current time + 10 mins to achieve the proper comparison time duration but am a but lost on how to use the time in conjunction with an If or a While to do the actual comparison. Both A and B are ints and C is a bool that would either be true or false depending upon the comparison.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Mark

Comment: Are A and B vars or return values of functions? If they're vars you could try to hind them behind descriptors and overload `__set__`, so each time one of them is set you can check and set C if needed

Comment: Is the question: "I have 2 variables which must satisfy the constraint  that A < B for a period of 10 mins"? ie, are you effectively wanting to "watch" two variables ?

Comment: I am a bit new to python so bare with me please. 'A' would be an ever changing variable that is coming in through a different data source and 'B' will be a constant to compare against. Jon - Yes I want to watch and compare the two and if the A < B case is true then I want to set C.

Comment: You'll have to use some form of multithreading to monitor the conditional at some regular intervals throughout the time period. This could end up being pretty complicated if other code depends on getting C as soon as it is set (in the event that it is set). One approach would be to use an event driven design, whereby if C is ever set, it emits a signal, much like the PyQT framework but not for GUIs.

Comment: Mark, could you post the **full** code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most simple solution would be a blocking while loop with sleep intervals. Note that this will only work if your A value can actually change in between (e.g., if it's the result of an SQL query or similar).

```
import datetime
import time

def getA():
  import random
  return random.random()

def getB():
  return .01

checkTime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
checkIntervalInSecs = .5

c = False
timeToStop = datetime.datetime.now() + checkTime
while(datetime.datetime.now() < timeToStop):
  if getA() < getB():
    c = True
    break
  time.sleep(checkIntervalInSecs)

print c
```

Comment: Thanks Hans, this appears to solve my problem. I have improvised upon it and it was the simplest for me to understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are looking for (or something similar), and this should be able to get you on the way to fixing the issue you are currently having.

```
import threading,random,time
results=[]
a=2
b=3
def check_values():
    if a<b:
        results.append("a<b")
    else:
        results.append("a>=b")
    print "Results-> "+",".join(str(x) for x in results)
check=Timer(30.0,check_values)
check.start()
try:
    while True:
        case=random.randrange(0,100)
        if case>=50:
            a+=1
        else:
            b+=1
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    check.stop()
    print "Final Results-> "+",".join(str(x) for x in results)
    exit(0)
```

Comment: This is a bit too complex for my Python skills but I will take it apart and see if I can understand it. Thanks IT Ninja I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties based approach, like this:

```
#a.py
import sys
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        print "New 'a' is: %s" % value
        ######## YOU CAN TEST HERE IF A > B OR WHATEVER ########

sys.modules[__name__] = Test()
```

Then:

```
>>>import a
>>>a.a
0
>>>a.a = 10
New 'a' is: 10
>>>a.a
10
>>>a.a = 100
New 'a' is: 100
```

It's bit hackish, and you have to explicitly use a.a, but it works.